# How to hide all the documents that were added after the page loaded in Meteor?

Tags: jquery, meteor

**Thanks everyone, I've fixed the problem using an iteration on Akshat's solution,
and a special thanks to Akshat how has already helped me solve another problem besides this one - quick, accurate and awesome problem-solving!**

OK, so i'm trying to create a post system in meteor and i want meteor to not show new posts, only count them and let the user decide when to show them. Thanks in advance, Daniel.

(Like twitter's x new Tweets)

Edit:
Hey everyone, thanks so far for all of your answers. The thing is, this is probably a very specific case because i am also implementing infinite scrolling so making it non-reactive won't help.

Code:

```
var Posts = new Meteor.Collection("posts");
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Session.set("current_page",1);
Template.posts.posts= function() {
        return Posts.find({}, {limit: Session.get("current_page")*20,sort: {created_at:-1}});
    };

function getDocHeight() {
    var D = document;
    return Math.max(
        Math.max(D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight),
        Math.max(D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight),
        Math.max(D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight)
    );
}
$(window).scroll(function() {   
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > getDocHeight() - 100) {
       Session.set("current_page",Session.get("current_page")+1);
   }
});
}
```

Comment: Please include code examples of what you have tried when posting questions.

Comment: Add the code to your question, not in the comments. You can always "edit" your question to add more information. You can also add formatting in the question so it is easier to read.  Thanks for posting your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the block helper `#constant` to mark a region as constant. It will be loaded when the template is first created, and only then.

[See the Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#constant)

Example: page.js

```
Template.page.collection = function() {
     return MyCollection.find({});
}
```

Example: page.html

```
<template name="page">
    {{#consant}}
         {{#each collection}}
              {{this}}
         {{/each}}
     {{/constant}}
 </template>
```

Comment: Great answer though not sure I could say mine's much better, this could also come in handy in making only a portion of it constant, such as the bit on wanting to keep a reactive count

Answer (score 1):

Lots of good answers! One other way is to use a non reactive query for your posts where you want it to behave this way. The new results are basically a result of [reactivity](http://docs.meteor.com/#reactivity), you can [disable reactivity](http://docs.meteor.com/#find) in your query

e.g

```
MyCollection.find({}, {reactive:false});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Collection.find().count() method

http://docs.meteor.com/#count